# The right way to call fire-and-forget method on a service-fabric service

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-remoting

I have a method on ServiceA that I need to call from ServiceB. The method takes upwards of 5 minutes to execute and I don't care about its return value. (Output from the method is handled another way)

I have setup my method in `IServiceA` like this:

```
[OneWay]
Task LongRunningMethod(int param1);
```

However that doesn't appear to run, because I am getting `System.TimeoutException: This can happen if message is dropped when service is busy or its long running operation and taking more time than configured Operation Timeout.`

One choice is to increase the timeout, but it seems that there should be a better way.
Is there?

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet how you call this method?

Comment: It looks like some messaging framework would be a great fit for your purposes (e.g. Azure Queue). Have you considered it? Another possible approach is to run the execution in a separate thread and immediately respond to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *fire and forget* or *long running operations* the best solution is using a message bus as a middle-ware that will handle this dependency between both process.

To do what you want without a middle-ware, your caller would have to worry about many things, like: Timeouts (like in your case), delivery guarantee(confirmation), Service availability, Exceptions and so on.

With the middle-ware the only worry your application logic need is the delivery guarantee, the rest should be handled by the middle-ware and the receiver.

There are many options, like:

- Azure Service Bus
- Azure Storage Queue
- MSMQ
- Event Hub
- and so on.

I would not recommend using the SF Communication, Task.Run(), Threads workarounds as many places suggests, because they will just bring you extra work and wont run as smooth as the middle-ware approach.